# Why am I doing i < a.length()-1 in my for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

The question is: Given two Strings, return the number of the positions where they contain the same substring with a length of 2 .

The code I wrote works but my question is why do I have to add the minus 1 to line 3 which is this part: i<a.length()-1

(I know it has something to do with me using (i,i+2))

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
  
  int count = 0;
  if (a.length() < b.length()) {
  for (int i=0; i<a.length()-1; i++) {
    if (a.substring(i,i+2).equals(b.substring(i,i+2))) {
      count++;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i=0; i<b.length()-1; i++) {
    if (b.substring(i,i+2).equals(a.substring(i,i+2))) {
      count++;
   }
   }
  }
return count;
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you attempted to take a 2-character substring from the last character of that string?

Comment: Have you written unit tests for this? What inputs have you tried?

Comment: So for all inputs they work. example: stringMatch("xxcaazz", "xxbaaz") → 3. Now when I change my for loop to i<a.length() without the -1, I get an out of bounds error.

Comment: I actually understand it now. It needs to be -1 so I can take the 2-character substring  and if it was normal a.length() I would be going out of bound of the string by 1. thanks guys!

Comment: This is why `length()-1` is used. `i` can not go to `length()` otherwise you will get the **out of Bounds** exception. You can see that the `substring()` method used in the code adds `2` to `i`, if you do not reduce the most `i` can go to by using `length() - 1` then when the loop gets to the last index, `i + 2` would put things out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the substring goes from the index i (included) to i + 2 (excluded), in order not to go out of the substring the loop needs to finish 1 step before.

Answer (score 0):

String.length() function returns length of the string, but when you access the characters you access it using index. That is why you have to do "-1".

For Example:

```
String s = "Hello";
```

Length is 5.
Index is from 0 to 4.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question. The `i < a.length()` appropriately handles accessing one less than the length